# How to create Configurable Product Programmatically

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, error, programmatically

I have found some question same my own but have not found out the answer. I want to create a configurable product. I have create a form to save the product and get the child product details in `configurable-matrix`:

[image]

[image]

But when I'm trying to save this product, the error `Option values are not specified.` appear. Can someone help me to save the product or just release another way to save a configurable product. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set attribute id and its value to it. For example this array of data:

```
public function getProductData($data = [])
{
    $productData = [
        'stock_data' => [
            'min_qty_allowed_in_shopping_cart' => [
                [
                    'record_id' => "0",
                    'customer_group_id' => "32000",
                    'min_sale_qty' => "",
                ]
            ],
            'deferred_stock_update' => "1",
            'use_config_deferred_stock_update' => "1",
            'min_qty' => "0",
            'max_sale_qty' => "10000",
            'notify_stock_qty' => "1",
            'qty_increments' => "1",
            'min_sale_qty' => "1",
            'use_config_manage_stock' => "1",
            'manage_stock' => "1",
            'use_config_min_qty' => "1",
            'use_config_max_sale_qty' => "1",
            'use_config_backorders' => "1",
            'backorders' => "0",
            'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => "1",
            'use_config_enable_qty_inc' => "1",
            'enable_qty_increments' => "0",
            'use_config_qty_increments' => "1",
            'use_config_min_sale_qty' => "1",
            'is_qty_decimal' => "0",
            'is_decimal_divided' => "0",
        ],
        'use_config_is_returnable' => "1",
        'gift_wrapping_available' => "1",
        'use_config_gift_wrapping_available' => "1",
        'gift_message_available' => "0",
        'use_config_gift_message_available' => "1",
        'links_title' => "Links",
        'links_purchased_separately' => "0",
        'samples_title' => "Samples",
        'attribute_set_id' => "4",
        'status' => $this->isParentProductEnable(),
        'affect_product_custom_options' => "1",
        'name' => $data['title'],
        'title_rewrite' => "",
        'price' => "100",
        'weight' => "",
        'url_key' => "",
        'gift_wrapping_price' => "",
        'special_price' => "",
        'cost' => "",
        'msrp' => "",
        'quantity_and_stock_status' => [
            'qty' => "",
            'is_in_stock' => "1"
        ],
        'is_returnable' => "2",
        'website_ids' => [$this->getWebsiteId($data['division'])],
        'tax_class_id' => "2",
        'product_has_weight' => "1",
        'visibility' => "4",
        'color' => "49",
        'size' => "91",
        'options_container' => "container2",
        'weltpixel_exclude_from_sitemap' => "0",
        'msrp_display_actual_price_type' => "0",
        'description' => "",
        'short_description' => "",
        'custom_layout_update' => "",
        'sku' => $data['product_code'],
        'meta_title' => $data['title'],
        'meta_keyword' => $data['title'],
        'meta_description' => "",
        'configurable_attributes_data' => [
            self::COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_ID => [
                'attribute_id' => self::COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,
                'code' => "color",
                'label' => "Color",
                'position' => "0",
                'values' => $this->getColorValue($data)
            ],
            self::SIZE_ATTRIBUTE_ID => [
                'attribute_id' => self::SIZE_ATTRIBUTE_ID,
                'code' => "size",
                'label' => "Size",
                'position' => "1",
                'values' => $this->getSizeValue($data)
            ]
        ],
        'associated_product_ids_serialized' => "[]",
        'configurable-matrix-serialized' => $this->getConfigurableMatrix($data)
    ];

    return $productData;
}
```

The important part is here:

```
 'configurable_attributes_data' => [
            self::COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_ID => [
                'attribute_id' => self::COLOR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,
                'code' => "color",
                'label' => "Color",
                'position' => "0",
                'values' => $this->getColorValue($data)
            ],
            self::SIZE_ATTRIBUTE_ID => [
                'attribute_id' => self::SIZE_ATTRIBUTE_ID,
                'code' => "size",
                'label' => "Size",
                'position' => "1",
                'values' => $this->getSizeValue($data)
            ]
        ],
'configurable-matrix-serialized' => $this->getConfigurableMatrix($data)
```

That would be the data indicating the simple products data.

Updated: These are methods for building simple products with configurable product:

```
private function getConfigurableMatrix($data)
{
    $jsonOutput = "[";
    // Get pair codes for matrix
    $colors = $data['colors'];
    $sizes = $this->getSizeArray($colors)['sizes'];
    $status = $this->isChildProductEnable();

    foreach ($colors as $color) {
        foreach ($sizes as $size) {
            $colorParam = [
                'id' => $this->getColorOptionId($color['color_id']),
                'lable' => $color['color_id']
            ];

            $sizeParam = [
                'id' => $this->getSizeOptionId($size['size']),
                'lable' => $size['size']
            ];

            $weight = $size['weight'] ? $size['weight'] : $this->getDefaultWeight();

            $jsonOutput .= $this->getConfigurableMatrixItem($data['title'], $size['sku'], $colorParam, $sizeParam, $size['quantity'], $weight, $size['price'], $status) . ",";
        }
    }

    $jsonOutput = rtrim($jsonOutput, ',');

    $jsonOutput .= "]";
    return $jsonOutput;
}



private function getConfigurableMatrixItem($name, $sku, $color = [], $size = [], $qty, $weight, $price, $status = 1)
{
    $item = [
        "id" => null,
        "product_link" => "",
        "name" => "$name {$color['lable']} {$size['lable']}",
        "sku" => "$sku",
        "status" => $status,
        "price" => "$price",
        "price_currency" => "$",
        "price_string" => "$$price",
        "weight" => "$weight",
        "qty" => "$qty",
        "variationKey" => "{$size['id']}-{$color['id']}",
        "configurable_attribute" => "{\"color\":\"{$color['id']}\",\"size\":\"{$size['id']}\"}",
        "thumbnail_image" => "",
        "media_gallery" => [
            "images" => []
        ],
        "image" => [],
        "attributes" => "Color : {$color['lable']}, Size: {$size['lable']}",
        "was_changed" => true,
        "canEdit" => 1,
        "newProduct" => 1,
        "record_id" => 0
    ];

    return json_encode($item);
}


private function getSizeOptionId($labelSize)
{
    if ($labelSize == '') return "";
    $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'size');

    $optionId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($labelSize);

    if (!$optionId) {
        // Create a new Option
        $option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
        //$option['value'][$lableSize][0] = $lableSize;
        $option['value']['size'][0] = $labelSize;

        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create();
        $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);

        $this->_eavConfig = $this->createObject('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
        $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'size');

        $optionId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($labelSize);

        $this->insertSwatch($optionId, 0, $labelSize);
    }

    return $optionId;
}


private function getColorOptionId($labelColor)
{
    if ($labelColor == '') return "";
    $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');

    $optionId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($labelColor);

    if (!$optionId) {
        // Create a new Option
        $option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
        //$option['value'][$labelColor][0] = $labelColor;
        $option['value']['color'][0] = $labelColor;

        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create();
        $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);

        $this->_eavConfig = $this->createObject('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
        $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');

        $optionId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($labelColor);

        $this->insertSwatch($optionId);
    }
    return $optionId;
}


private function insertSwatch($optionId, $type = 1, $value = "#ffffff")
{
    $swatch = $this->createObject('Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch');

    $swatch->setData([
        'option_id' => $optionId,
        'store_id' => 0,
        'type' => $type,
        'value' => $value
    ]);

    $swatch->save();
}
```

Comment: How can I call the function: `$this->getConfigurableMatrix($data)`

Comment: This is my function to build the json data for simple product. Do you want to see it ?

Comment: Of course yes!!

Comment: please, see my updated answer

Comment: Any luck @NeroPhung ?

Comment: No, seems like the issue become from `$product->getExtensionAttributes();` function. So the error `Option values are not specified` still appear. I'm trying to setExtensionAttributes()

Comment: For me it is working with product with supper attributes : Color and Size.

You have to check the attribute you want build for simple products. 

Then make sure its value is exist in the system.

I have built an application to import the product data form external system using API to insert product and it is working pretty fine.